# Rust Python not installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, termux

I've been using Termux for a long time, but I can't solve this problem. Why when I want to install **Rust** using **pip**.  After the message: **Using cached matplotlib-3.5.1.tar.gz** (35.3 MB) nothing happens for an hour now.

Answer (score 2):

That's the [Ribo-Seq Unit Step Transformation](https://pypi.org/project/RUST/) package.

This tool is designed for ribo-seq data and produces a metafootprint profile that reveals the influence of mRNA features such as codons/amino acids on the relative read density in the sample across the entire ribosome and nascent peptide region. The Kullback-Leibler divergence across these sites is also provided.

I think you're trying to install rust compiler. For that you need to use this command `pkg install rust`

Answer (score 1):

You could try **updating** pip to the **latest version** by `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. And then try `pip install RUST`

If it doesn't work you could try **uninstalling** `Rust` first by `pip uninstall RUST`. And then **reinstall** it by `pip install RUST`